# What false means in the android ids.xml file

Tags: android

I notice that in the res/value folder of some android app's, there exists an ids.xml file with some item have false value
what false means?
can anyone tell me ,thank!

Answer (score 6):

I believe you see these when you decompile an apk file. After some trial and error, I found out that the `false` does not actually do anything. You can put anything instead of a boolean.

So why is false is appearing? According to my experiments if you create a file ids.xml in your project after I compile my apk I would see exactly the same line in the compiled ids.xml as I see in my projects ids.xml. However, if I do not place my id in the ids.xml and create it using `@+id/myId` I will see a tag in the compiled ids.xml with a `false` as its value. I hope it answers your qestion

**My ids.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item name="test_id" type="id"/>
    <item name="test_id2" type="id">false</item>
    <item name="test_id3" type="id">This is a test String</item>
    <item name="test_id4" type="id">749274927492</item>
</resources>
```

**In My Layout**

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/myId"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

**Generated ids.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item type="id" name="test_id" />
    <item type="id" name="test_id2">false</item>
    <item type="id" name="test_id3">This is a test String</item>
    <item type="id" name="test_id4">1950617988</item>
    <item type="id" name="myId">false</item>
    <item type="id" name="action_bar_activity_content" />
    <item type="id" name="action_menu_divider" />
    <item type="id" name="action_menu_presenter" />
    <item type="id" name="action_bar_root">false</item>
    <item type="id" name="action_bar_container">false</item>
    <item type="id" name="action_bar">false</item>
    <item type="id" name="action_context_bar">false</item>
    <item type="id" name="split_action_bar">false</item>
    ....
</resources>
```

Comment: You right about`when you decompile an apk file`  ^^

Answer (score 4):

You can refer this , everything explained beautifully here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html

Comment: thans, i checked that page, but still not explain the node value "false" is for what

Comment: Up voted because it helped me in defining extra ids than defining with UI widget in layouts but not giving the answer of the question.